# Can apples, peaches, almonds or apricots be used for reducing lactose content in milk?

Tags: dairy, molecular-gastronomy

According to this paper:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5429307/#!po=13.1579

"β-Galactosidase is found in bacteria, fungi, and yeasts. In plants, it is mainly found in almonds, peaches, apples, and apricots."

Supposedly, β-Galactosidase is a lactase enzyme that can break down lactose. Could this mean that, say, keeping almonds or apples or peaches or apricots overnight in milk could reduce the lactose content of milk?

As far as I've read about different types of lactase enzymes, they can have different optimal temperature and pH ranges for optimal activity. I tried digging more into temperature and pH ranges for the lactase enzymes found in the above four foods (assuming they are capable of breaking down lactose in milk) but could not find any further references or studies.

Comment: Gut reaction: this would be very attractive to many people, because it would be a) easy, b) in line with common health beliefs (fruits=healthy, capsule from the pharmacy=suspicious) and c) a great candidate for folk wisdom ("soak some apples in your milk so you don't get bellyaches"). So if it did work, it would be ubiquitously used and widely known.

Comment: @rumtscho Very apposite use of the phrase 'gut reaction' there

Comment: If you add fruit to milk and let it steep overnight, it will likely curdle because of the acids in the fruit. It won't be milk any more!!  In Indian cuisine, they often make a kind of yoghurt that Indians often call "curd" or "dahi" using fruit or vegetables steeped in milk overnight  to make a starter for its preparation. I'm not too sure of the exact chemical/biological processes involved in making dahi this way, but it involves fermentation like when making yoghurt - I assume bacteria are involved as well as the fruit acids.

Comment: @BillyKerr Most fruit doesn't have nearly enough acid to curdle milk. I also don't know for sure what is involved in the indian yogurt method, but I don't think that people do it in order to reduce lactose. Also, not even regular yogurt, where we know that the bacteria involved devour lactose, is low on lactose.